# Transform data from header level to line level

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How do I transform a data from header level to line level with plsql?

Suppose I have a table with the following:

```
Project | Code1 | Code2 | Code3
      1 |   a   |   b   |   c
      2 |   a   |   d   |
```

How do I split the code columns and combine them into one column (see below):

```
Project | Code
      1 |  a
      1 |  b
      1 |  c
      2 |  a
      2 |  d
```

I tried "Union All" but the query took a long time. Maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: What version of Oracle you are using?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Version 11g

Comment: Since you are using 11g version of RDBMS you can make use of `unpivot` operator. [Here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fddc9/1)

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov: I am joining multiple tables. Do I insert the unpivot between from statements (sekect > from > join on > unpivot > join on > where) or (select > from > join on > join on > unpivot > where)? and how am I suppose to group these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `unpivot` command for this:

```
select project, codevalue
from yourtable
unpivot (codevalue
         for code in (code1, code2, code3)
  )
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d320d/4)

Comment: i see code1, code2 in the second column, OP output is showing value of code1 column that is a,b,c etc.

Comment: @Rajesh -- sorry, never updated the fiddle... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d320d/4.  My original post used the column name (code) instead of the column value (codevalue).  Thanks!

Comment: @sgeddes I am joining multiple tables. Do I insert the unpivot between from statements (sekect > from > join on > unpivot > join on > where) or (select > from > join on > join on > unpivot > where)? and how am I suppose to group these?

Comment: @Futochan -- `unpivot` would come after all `joins`.  If that doesn't resolve you're issue, put the above in a subquery with just the needed values.  `select fieldlist from (above query as is) tablealias join...`